# PHP - Insert SQL Error

Tags: php, mysql

Database layout:

```
rid (auto increment) (primary key) (255)
song (varchar) (120)
artist (varchar) (30)
by(varchar) (33)
key(varchar) (60)
```

PHP code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Requests (song,artist,by,key) 
        VALUES ('$song','$artist','$by','$key')";
        if($this->db->query($sql))
        {
            die("true");
        }
        echo 'false: ' . $this->db->error;
```

Error:

> false: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'by,key) VALUES ('testsong','testing','kyle','example')' at line 1

Help? I have debuged for ages, I can't see whats wrong with that SQL? Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"I have debuged for ages, I can't see whats wrong with that SQL?"* - `right syntax to use near 'by,key)` - MySQL even told you where it "starts".

Comment: Yes, so I checked the database columns where correct, checked syntax - sorry that I didn't know that severed words existed, I'll try know things I've never been taught next time, don't worry @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need back ticks for SQL-related names, also `by` and `key` are MySQL [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html):

```
INSERT INTO Requests (`song`,`artist`,`by`,`key`)
```

Comment: That is the reason, oh god.. I changed the database column name from key to api_key and by to who and its worked, thanks for this

Comment: Will do but got to wait 7mins buddy :) Check back in 7mins ;)

Comment: @KyleE4K You're welcome, glad that it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 6):

You need to use backtick for `BY` and `KEY` columns, both are mysql reserve words

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Requests (`song`,`artist`,`by`,`key`) 
        VALUES ('$song','$artist','$by','$key')";
```

[MYSQL Reserve Words List](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)

**Side Note:**

I suggest you that, please do not use reserve words and keywords for table or column names.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query to insert data in Requests table

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Requests (`song`,`artist`,`by`,`key`) 
    VALUES ('".$song."','".$artist."','".$by."','".$key."')";
    if ($this->db->query($sql)) {
        die("true");
    }
    echo 'false: ' . $this->db->error;
```

the main problem in the asked question's query is apostrophe on both side of column name is missed as (song, artist, by, key) Should be ('song', 'artist', 'by', key')

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.